# How to redirect default.php to /

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect default.php to / (path with no arguments) in Apache with .htaccess, but so far I have not find a way to make this work. If I do something like:

`Redirect permanent /default.php powerkaraoke.com/`

I get 500 error. Other redirects work fine, for example powerkaraoke.com->www.powerkaraoke.com.

What is the proper way of doing this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you really want a redirect or use default.php for /? In that case you would need mod_dir with DirectoryIndex set to default.php, not .htaccess

Comment: I am struggling with a problem that our root page is not indexed by Bing. One of the possible solutions was to redirect default.php. I do not want to reconfigure the site as the change you propose might break something elsewhere, and thought there is a simple solution using htaccess. But it seems that you are right and this is not a thing that can be done with htaccess.

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^default.php$ / [R=301,L]
```

I think that should work.

Comment: I think removing / from ^/default.php$ will be works.. try ^default.php$.

Comment: @Gumbo: What's wrong with this? mod_rewrite works fine in .htaccess.

Comment: Query strings wouldn't run in this case, like, "default.php?etc=etc" would be possible. Remove the `$` from `...default.php$` and add a `Query String Append` to the end: `[R=301,L,QSA]`.

And better yet, if you are sure that you've never given out a link including "default.php", you can give a 404, since it's legally and SEO-wise non-existent.

Comment: @Will Vousden: alifity said it.

Comment: @Gumbo: Yes, obviously it is .htaccess.

Comment: @Piotr K: Try adding "Options +FollowSymLinks" on the line above "RewriteEngine on". Does the server even support mod_rewrite?

Comment: @Ivarska: Exactly. That’s why you need to remove the contextual path prefix from the pattern. Just like alifity said (although he might not actually be aware of the reason).

Comment: I have +FollowSymLinks. mod_rewrite works (eg. powerkaraoke.com->www.powerkaraoke.com), but I cannot get it to work for default.php.

Answer (score 1):

[`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) requires an absolute path or absolute URL:

> The *new URL* should be an absolute URL beginning with a scheme and hostname, but a URL-path beginning with a slash may also be used, in which case the scheme and hostname of the current server will be added.

But what you’ve provided is just a relative path. So try this:

```
Redirect permanent /default.php /
```

But as `Redirect` just matches the given path prefix and adds remaining path segments (e.g. `/default.php/foo/bar` gets redirected to `/foo/bar`), you might want to use [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) instead:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/default\.php$ /
```

Comment: This is what I tried initially. It causes Internal Server Error with code 500.

Comment: @Piotr K: *What* did you try? Both?

Comment: Yes, the first gives error 500, the second 404. And this is not only for default.php, but for powerkaraoke.com/ as well.

Comment: @Piotr K: Do you use any further rewrites/redirects that could interfere with this one?

Comment: None that I am aware of. There might be CPanel doing something behind the scenes with default.php set as the name of index page, but no redirects are defined in CPanel explicitely.